# What does error code 1853227065 mean in minecraft launcher log

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

For some reason Minecraft has started crashing on my Windows 10 and even though the launcher log writes out the exit code I haven't been able to find any information on google. It seems to happen at random and not with any particular player action or workbench construction. This is what I get from the launcher:

```
[10:46:56 INFO]: Looking for old natives & assets to clean up...
[10:53:57 ERROR]: Game ended with bad state (exit code 1853227065)
```

These are my specs:

- Minecraft version 1.9.2
- Minecraft launcher version 1.6.61
- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit with 16GB memory
- Java version 1.8.0_77

Here's a full crash log:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// This doesn't make any sense!

Time: 17/04/16 16:26
Description: Exception in world tick

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.resize(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(Unknown Source)
    at bnl.a(SourceFile:2211)
    at aht.m(SourceFile:642)
    at aht.a(SourceFile:637)
    at aht.c(SourceFile:2202)
    at aht.w(SourceFile:2083)
    at ase.n(SourceFile:999)
    at aht.a(SourceFile:2009)
    at bkr.a(SourceFile:273)
    at bkr.j(SourceFile:156)
    at bkr.d(SourceFile:96)
    at bcc.t(SourceFile:1658)
    at bcc.av(SourceFile:962)
    at bcc.a(SourceFile:392)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at java.util.HashMap.resize(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(Unknown Source)
    at bnl.a(SourceFile:2211)
    at aht.m(SourceFile:642)
    at aht.a(SourceFile:637)
    at aht.c(SourceFile:2202)
    at aht.w(SourceFile:2083)
    at ase.n(SourceFile:999)
    at aht.a(SourceFile:2009)
    at bkr.a(SourceFile:273)
    at bkr.j(SourceFile:156)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 1 total; [bmq['onhelmosar'/52329, l='MpServer', x=-5.27, y=74.00, z=33.73]]
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 1024, 1024
    Level seed: 0
    Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (8,64,8), Chunk: (at 8,4,8 in 0,0; contains blocks 0,0,0 to 15,255,15), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
    Level time: 1972321 game time, 2863059 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 45 total; [yr['Zombie Pigman'/52864, l='MpServer', x=-76.50, y=102.00, z=-18.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52802, l='MpServer', x=-64.38, y=102.00, z=-47.20], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52803, l='MpServer', x=-62.72, y=102.00, z=-42.80], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52804, l='MpServer', x=-62.81, y=101.00, z=-46.56], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52741, l='MpServer', x=-64.50, y=82.00, z=100.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52805, l='MpServer', x=-63.18, y=102.00, z=-45.84], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52742, l='MpServer', x=-68.70, y=83.00, z=93.93], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52743, l='MpServer', x=-59.50, y=82.00, z=96.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52871, l='MpServer', x=66.50, y=54.00, z=60.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52872, l='MpServer', x=66.50, y=54.00, z=62.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52873, l='MpServer', x=68.50, y=54.00, z=62.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52874, l='MpServer', x=68.50, y=54.00, z=61.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52747, l='MpServer', x=-65.50, y=82.00, z=99.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52879, l='MpServer', x=28.50, y=14.00, z=-24.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52754, l='MpServer', x=-62.50, y=103.00, z=-38.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52755, l='MpServer', x=-66.50, y=85.00, z=23.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52819, l='MpServer', x=33.50, y=113.00, z=-0.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52821, l='MpServer', x=72.50, y=6.00, z=-3.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52822, l='MpServer', x=73.50, y=6.00, z=-0.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52767, l='MpServer', x=-78.50, y=103.00, z=-8.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52833, l='MpServer', x=33.59, y=5.00, z=-37.13], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52834, l='MpServer', x=38.50, y=5.00, z=-30.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52898, l='MpServer', x=71.50, y=37.00, z=4.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52835, l='MpServer', x=38.50, y=5.00, z=-30.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52899, l='MpServer', x=74.65, y=37.00, z=3.52], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52774, l='MpServer', x=6.50, y=46.00, z=17.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52775, l='MpServer', x=-70.50, y=92.00, z=40.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52839, l='MpServer', x=16.50, y=111.00, z=5.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52776, l='MpServer', x=-67.50, y=92.00, z=41.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52840, l='MpServer', x=35.50, y=32.00, z=11.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52777, l='MpServer', x=-67.50, y=92.00, z=37.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52841, l='MpServer', x=37.50, y=32.00, z=9.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52784, l='MpServer', x=-55.50, y=94.00, z=0.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52785, l='MpServer', x=-57.50, y=94.00, z=0.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52853, l='MpServer', x=-81.50, y=13.00, z=-29.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52790, l='MpServer', x=-61.50, y=33.00, z=92.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52791, l='MpServer', x=50.81, y=54.00, z=38.48], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52856, l='MpServer', x=-55.50, y=37.00, z=66.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52857, l='MpServer', x=-56.50, y=37.00, z=66.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52858, l='MpServer', x=-56.50, y=37.00, z=66.50], bmq['onhelmosar'/52329, l='MpServer', x=-5.27, y=74.00, z=33.73], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52796, l='MpServer', x=26.50, y=27.00, z=-30.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52797, l='MpServer', x=36.50, y=41.00, z=-2.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52861, l='MpServer', x=-74.50, y=102.00, z=-24.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52863, l='MpServer', x=-73.50, y=102.00, z=-21.50]]
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
    Server brand: vanilla
    Server type: Integrated singleplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at bkr.a(SourceFile:365)
    at bcc.t(SourceFile:1665)
    at bcc.av(SourceFile:962)
    at bcc.a(SourceFile:392)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 1 total; [bmq['onhelmosar'/52329, l='MpServer', x=-5.27, y=74.00, z=33.73]]
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 1024, 1024
    Level seed: 0
    Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (8,64,8), Chunk: (at 8,4,8 in 0,0; contains blocks 0,0,0 to 15,255,15), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
    Level time: 1972321 game time, 2863059 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 45 total; [yr['Zombie Pigman'/52864, l='MpServer', x=-76.50, y=102.00, z=-18.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52802, l='MpServer', x=-64.38, y=102.00, z=-47.20], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52803, l='MpServer', x=-62.72, y=102.00, z=-42.80], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52804, l='MpServer', x=-62.81, y=101.00, z=-46.56], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52741, l='MpServer', x=-64.50, y=82.00, z=100.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52805, l='MpServer', x=-63.18, y=102.00, z=-45.84], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52742, l='MpServer', x=-68.70, y=83.00, z=93.93], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52743, l='MpServer', x=-59.50, y=82.00, z=96.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52871, l='MpServer', x=66.50, y=54.00, z=60.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52872, l='MpServer', x=66.50, y=54.00, z=62.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52873, l='MpServer', x=68.50, y=54.00, z=62.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52874, l='MpServer', x=68.50, y=54.00, z=61.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52747, l='MpServer', x=-65.50, y=82.00, z=99.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52879, l='MpServer', x=28.50, y=14.00, z=-24.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52754, l='MpServer', x=-62.50, y=103.00, z=-38.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52755, l='MpServer', x=-66.50, y=85.00, z=23.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52819, l='MpServer', x=33.50, y=113.00, z=-0.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52821, l='MpServer', x=72.50, y=6.00, z=-3.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52822, l='MpServer', x=73.50, y=6.00, z=-0.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52767, l='MpServer', x=-78.50, y=103.00, z=-8.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52833, l='MpServer', x=33.59, y=5.00, z=-37.13], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52834, l='MpServer', x=38.50, y=5.00, z=-30.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52898, l='MpServer', x=71.50, y=37.00, z=4.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52835, l='MpServer', x=38.50, y=5.00, z=-30.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52899, l='MpServer', x=74.65, y=37.00, z=3.52], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52774, l='MpServer', x=6.50, y=46.00, z=17.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52775, l='MpServer', x=-70.50, y=92.00, z=40.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52839, l='MpServer', x=16.50, y=111.00, z=5.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52776, l='MpServer', x=-67.50, y=92.00, z=41.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52840, l='MpServer', x=35.50, y=32.00, z=11.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52777, l='MpServer', x=-67.50, y=92.00, z=37.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52841, l='MpServer', x=37.50, y=32.00, z=9.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52784, l='MpServer', x=-55.50, y=94.00, z=0.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52785, l='MpServer', x=-57.50, y=94.00, z=0.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52853, l='MpServer', x=-81.50, y=13.00, z=-29.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52790, l='MpServer', x=-61.50, y=33.00, z=92.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52791, l='MpServer', x=50.81, y=54.00, z=38.48], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52856, l='MpServer', x=-55.50, y=37.00, z=66.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52857, l='MpServer', x=-56.50, y=37.00, z=66.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52858, l='MpServer', x=-56.50, y=37.00, z=66.50], bmq['onhelmosar'/52329, l='MpServer', x=-5.27, y=74.00, z=33.73], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52796, l='MpServer', x=26.50, y=27.00, z=-30.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52797, l='MpServer', x=36.50, y=41.00, z=-2.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52861, l='MpServer', x=-74.50, y=102.00, z=-24.50], yr['Zombie Pigman'/52863, l='MpServer', x=-73.50, y=102.00, z=-21.50]]
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
    Server brand: vanilla
    Server type: Integrated singleplayer server

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.9.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (x86) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_77, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 9348136 bytes (8 MB) / 523501568 bytes (499 MB) up to 523501568 bytes (499 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 12, tallocated: 94
    Launched Version: 1.9.2
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: GeForce GTX 590/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.5.0 NVIDIA 353.82, NVIDIA Corporation
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using GL 1.3 texture combiners.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.
VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.

    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460 CPU @ 3.20GHz
```

Does anyone know what the error code means?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the full log somewhere?

Comment: Those error codes are largely meaningless. We're going to need a crash log to be able to figure out the issue. Take a look at [this meta FAQ](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/how-do-i-ask-a-good-minecraft-bug-crash-question) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @MrLemon Thanks for the link - I did not know about the crash log. I have added a link in the question text

Comment: @boomshanka alright, great. I moved the log to the question itself and I can already see the issue and how to fix it. I'll try to answer as soon as the question is reopened (unless someone beats me to it).

Comment: Until you edit the question I'll put it here - You have `-Xmx512M` in java options. That means, that regardless of everything your game can't allocate more than 512 MB of RAM. It wasn't enough. Find where to change that in launcher options to 2048-4096M to fix your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You need to allocate more memory to the game.

Your question states that you have 16GB of RAM in your computer, which is a lot. However, the game is still running out of memory:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

The reason is that while, yes, your computer may have 16GB RAM, Minecraft is not allowed to use more than 500MB, as shown in the system details part of your crash log:

```
Memory: 9348136 bytes (8 MB) / 523501568 bytes (499 MB) up to 523501568 bytes (499 MB)
JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
```

This limitation is caused by the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) flags, specifically `-Xmx512M`. To increase the amount of memory the game is allowed to allocate, follow these steps:

1. Open your Minecraft launcher
2. In the bottom left corner, click on <kbd>Edit Profile</kbd>.
3. Towards the bottom of the new window, theres a tick labeled "JVM arguments", followed by a text box. Check this box if it isn't checked already.
4. In the text box, look for `-Xmx`, followed by some number and a letter, such as `512M`. This number shows the amount of memory the JVM can allocate *at most*. In this case, this is 512 Megabytes (hence `M`). I suggest changing the number to `2G` to allocate 2 Gigabytes (`G`) of memory, which is sufficient to run vanilla Minecraft. Setting it any higher can actually have a [detrimental effect](http://vazkii.us/uncategorized/a-semi-technical-explanation-of-why-you-shouldnt-allocate-too-much-ram-to-minecraft/).
5. Save the profile and launch the game. You can see the amount of memory allocated, as well as the maximum in the top-right corner of the debug screen (<kbd>F3</kbd>) in game.

Comment: Strangely enough, the -Xmx setting was set to 1GB and it appears that I cannot allocate 2GB without running out of heap space, but that is for another thread

Answer (score -2):

After looking at the crash log it looks like the game ran out of memory because of the video settings being set too high. After setting everything to low I have been able to play for hours without any crash.

Comment: Allocate more memory to the game.